# how do i truncate a filename using unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

i want to change the filename of this

```
AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D180226.T214510.M254
```

to

```
AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D180226214510254
```

Comment: Try: `mv AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D180226.T214510.M254 
AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D180226214510254` (all on one line).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D180226.T214510.M254"
extract=$(echo $filename | sed -n "s/\(AFTEPRD.TRANSFER.S.EBKI.D\)\([0-9]*\)*.T\([0-9]*\)*.M\([0-9]*\)*/\1\2\3\4/p")
echo "Renaming: $filename to $extract"
```

Instead of `echo`, you can use `mv`.

Comment: ``mv ${filename} ${extract}``. For more details, type ``man mv`` in the terminal.

Comment: @VishvasStark : You can not expect to present just more and more examples and let people figure out solutions which happen to work with your example, and next time you come up with a new naming pattern. You have one solution which is based on a regular expression. If you pattern can be described by a regexp, simply adapt this solution. If your renaming pattern can not be described by a regexp, we need to find a new method, but in this case, you need to first define exactly in what way you want to shorten your file names.